# DataTables.js - Dynamic Variable flagging error on .page() API Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, onchange

So, I am creating a custom navigation for my DataTable via a select dropdown.
The value of each option it equal to each page, but running it through a jQuery on Change function flags a DataTable error that points me back to the the API documentation.

***HTML:***

```
<div class='form-group'>
     <label>Student</label>
     <select name='filter-name' class='form-control' id='table-name'>
          <option value='0'>1</option>
          <option value='1'>2</option>
          <option value='2'>3</option>
          <option value='3'>4</option>
          <option value='4'>5</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

***JS:***

```
$("#example").DataTable({});
var table = $("#example").DataTable();

$("#table-name").on('change', function(){
     var pageVar = $(this).val();
     table.page(pageVar).draw('page');
});
```

I continue to get this warning:

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - Unknown paging action: 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/5
```

But if I hardcode an integer instead of `pageVar`, it works just fine.

Comment: Try to put `parseInt(pageVar)`.

Comment: that was it. damn. You'd think with the page() API call accepting integers OR strings it wouldn't have any issue differentiating the two.

Comment: If you pass any value as String it will check with the accepted string values `first, next, previous, last`. If no one is found, it will throw the error. check this: https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as per [document](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()):

**This parameter can take two forms:**

1. Integer - The page index to jump to (0 is the first page!)
2. String - An action to take:

   1. `first` - Jump to the first page.
   2. `next` - Jump to the next page.
   3. `previous` - Jump to the previous page.
   4. `last` - Jump to the last page.

So, you should take care of the `Integer` value.

> parseInt(pageVar)

**Check the description of error [here](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/5):**

> The built-in page() method has a number of options for changing the page, for example, you can pass in the string next to jump to the next page. This error occurs when the option passed in is not known.